How to Replace TCP Communication for a PWA Using Azure Services
We currently have a TCP-based communication setup with a third-party system integrated into our Android APK. The setup maintains TCP sessions, allowing us to receive real-time alerts whenever a new case requires attention.
We are now migrating to a Progressive Web App (PWA) that will be deployed in the cloud. Since PWAs are browser-based, maintaining TCP-based communication is not feasible.
Is there any Azure service that can help us achieve a similar functionality?
The key requirements are:

Persistent session management for real-time communication.
Efficient delivery of alerts from the third-party system to our PWA.
We are exploring options such as WebSockets or server-side solutions but would prefer an Azure-native service if one exists.

Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

you can consider using either Azure SignalR Service or Azure Web PubSub Service.

WebSocket support is there in azure checkout-  WebSocket support in Azure | Microsoft Learn  and App Service on Linux FAQ | Microsoft Learn
Additionally, as an alternative solution for communication for your Progressive Web App using Azure services, you can consider using either Azure SignalR or Azure Web PubSub. Both services can help you achieve real-time communication without the need for TCP sessions, making them suitable alternatives for your PWA.
References

What is Azure Web PubSub service?
What is Azure SignalR Service?

